# Importing Value for a Instance Profile from different stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating a InstanceProfile in CloudFormation Template and trying to import IAM role that was created in different stack. When I try to launch the template which is importing the IAM role, I'm facing template validation error:

```
Template error: the attribute in Fn::ImportValue must be a string or a function that returns a string
```

My CloudFormation Template snippet for importing the IAM role is shown below:

```
  InstanceProfile:
      Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
      Properties:
        Path: "/"
        Roles:
          -
            Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub "${VPCStackName}-TesRole"
```

The output of the Tes Role a is string:

```
  TesRole:
    Description: Ec2 role
    Value:
      !Ref TesRole
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-TesRole"
```

Value of the output is `StackName-TesRole-MKNLV7ORDDRY`

I have tried different syntaxes, still getting the template validation error. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: In the source stack, what value is being output as `TesRole`? Is it a string, an ARN, an object...? Can you edit your question to include the part of the source template that has the Role and the Output?